# How to detect performance degradation due to ram module mismatch

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

I need to add memory (DDR4 3200) to my motherboard. My system's existing RAM module brand is hard to find and expensive. I am considering buying another popular brand with half cost. The specificans of the module I am considering is the same (speed, size, non-ecc, rank)

I learned that I can mix memory module brands as long as they are the same speed.

I know a few memory diagnosis tools that detect system memory stability issues (like blue screen). The tools I know include memtext86 and "Windows Memory Diagnosis".

Is there any memory diagnostic tool that can help detect performance degradation due to ram spec mismatch?

Comment: If you can purchase the same frequency that is best solution otherwise the faster module will be down clocked. Outside of benchmarks you will be unable to detect performance impacts of using slower memory.

Comment: memtest86  I think will give you a memory speed benchmark during its tests.